# Javascript If statement - should be true, evaluating to false

Tags: javascript, if-statement

The code in question:

```
console.log(marker.getIcon() == selectedDestinationMarkerImage);
console.log(marker.getIcon());
console.log(selectedDestinationMarkerImage);

if(marker.getIcon() == selectedDestinationMarkerImage)
{
    return true;
}
```

The console output

```
false
Object{url: "images/icons/dd-end.png", size: W}
Object{url: "images/icons/dd-end.png", size: W}
```

---

The icon on the `marker` is set to `selectedDestinationMarkerImage` at some point before this check. I would actually expect even the `===` comparison to return true. (*I tried that as well, it doesn't*)

Comment: Why do you think it should be `true`?

Comment: Object equality in JS is complicated; if `getIcon` generates a new object each time, then they are not equivalent, even if the keys/values are the same.

Comment: @melpomene When the page is loaded, `marker.setIcon(selectedDestinationMarkerImage)` is used.

Comment: @Mathletics It's definitely confusing, after looking up the `getIcon` method it just returns the object that it has.. I've decided to side-step the problem and just compare on the .url of the objects.

Comment: @DoubleDouble You'd have to show the code for `setIcon` and `getIcon` and the definition of `marker`.

Comment: @melpomene [Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers) comes from the Google Maps API, but what I have works so its fine.